# Java e Bancos de Dados Off-line

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados

Preciso de uma ajuda com banco de dados em Java. Quero fazer um banco de dados que o programa gera um arquivo, como por exemplo "database.db" e esse arquivo eu posso acessar sem precisar de nenhuma conexão com internet, usando apenas o arquivo mencionado.

Como eu faço isso?

Como se chama esse tipo de banco de dados "off-line"?

Posso usar o Access?

Comment: A sua aplicação é desktop ou web?

Comment: você quer "fazer um banco de dados" ? ou você quer usar um banco de dados? a princípio todos os bancos de dados grava os dados em algum lugar/arquivo e você pode acessa-lo localhost ou remoto.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Baixe e instale o [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) e o driver para o [SQLite](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads)

SQLite é um sistema de banco de dados sem servidor, no qual o banco será um único arquivo no computador. Há mais informações sobre o mesmo na [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

## Criar o banco

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteJDBC
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Banco aberto com sucesso");
  }
}
```

## Criar uma tabela

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteJDBC
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
      System.out.println("Banco de dados fora aberto com sucesso");

      stmt = c.createStatement();
      String sql = "CREATE TABLE TABELA " +
                   "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," +
                   " NOME           TEXT    NOT NULL, " + 
                   " IDADE            INT     NOT NULL)"; 
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      stmt.close();
      c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("A tabela TABELA foi criada com sucesso");
  }
}
```

Nota: poderia usar o Access (não recomendo por seu foco ser o uso local). Mas teria de fazer a conexão de qualquer jeito a única diferença é que o host do seu db seria `localhost`. Se quiser ver sobre como usar o Access sugiro que veja [esse link](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/03/ms-access-database-connectivity-in-java.html)

Answer (score 4):

Outra solucao seria utilizar HSQLDB.
http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2010/06/using-hypersql-hsqldb.html.
Voce somente precisa configura-lo para guardar os dados em um arquivo e nao na memoria, como é  a configuracao default.

Comment: +1 Eu já usei o HSQLDB no passado (em projetos reais) e funciona muito bem! Em geral eu recomendo o SQLite mesmo (pois o suporte a ele é mais amplo, caso o banco precise ser acessado por programas em outras linguagens), mas para uma solução Java puro o HSQLDB é uma excelente opção.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra opção, é usar o H2 Database.
Usei-o em uma aplicação não tem muito tempo, e agradei dele.

[Clique aqui para acessar a página oficial do H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)

[Clique aqui](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_eclipselink) para um tutorial com o Eclipse, ou [Clique aqui](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_netbeans) para um tutorial com NetBeans, ou ainda [clique aqui](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html) pra a página de tutoriais do H2 Database.